# How to remove dates from band in Simile Timeline

Tags: javascript, timeline, simile

Is there a parameter in the `theme` or in `createBandInfo` where I can turn off the date labels for one band?

Preferably without affecting the dotted interval lines.

Or is there maybe a way to use css to format the dates?

Timeline documentation is spread into several places. I checked MIT, GoogleCode and the Simile wiki but could not find the info anywhere.

The background is, that I'd like to have several narrow bands to group certain events to the same height but I don't want the dates to be re-labeled on every band.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have discovered this already: Setting the css declaration for the .timeline-date-label class to 'display: none' might do what you want. You can set it by individual band(s) too by including the .timeline-band-n class, eg.:

```
.timeline-band-2 .timeline-date-label {
    display: none;
}
```

in the source, the machinery for generating the date labels can be found at:
timeline_source-2.3.0/src/webapp/api/scripts/ether-painters.js

And I suppose you could tinker with things there as well